# How to calculate if Anonymous users reach to 6 hours old?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, anonymous

In [How does peer review for edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/167443) the author said that "*Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 6 hours old.*"

And I want to know, How does the Stack Overflow calculate if Anonymous users reached to 6 hours old? Is it according to the accumulated time that Anonymous users stay in any Stack Overflow pages?

Comment: downvoting because...why?  the poster misunderstood and asked a clarifying question?

Comment: Downvoting questions because the OP misunderstood policy is not appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simple: was the question or answer posted more than 6 hours ago?  If yes, then it is editable by anonymous users.

You seem to be misunderstanding that quote. The time pertains to the length of time the question or answer has been in existence, not the amount of time the user has spent on the site.

Comment: Thank you. I think I made a mistake.